# iPhone Caller ID Retrieval - TOOLCHAIN

Tags: iphone, sdk, toolchain, cydia

I was wondering if there was any way to get the Caller ID of an incoming call on the iPhone, I am currently playing with SBTelephony.h (SpringBoard header) and the CoreTelephony.framework and I am not really seeing how to do this.  I am planning on using this for a dylib using WinChain/ToolChain etc. Thank you!

Comment: Also, is it possible that what I am looking for is within the "SBCall...".h files?  I found the method

-(void)_handleCallerIDEvent:(struct _CTCall *)arg1;
(This is using Class-Dump 3.3 btw)

how would I manipulate that if it is genuinely what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Given a `CTCallRef` you should be able to call `CTCallCopyAddress` and `CTCallCopyName` to get the call details.

Alternatively you may wish to look at [observing telephony events manually](http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/02/when-it-comes-to-the.html).

Comment: thanks for the response. how do i get ahold of the CoreTelephony.framework, im having trouble finding much on it out there

Comment: For the most part I just class-dump/nm the framework I'm targeting. If I need help with the parameters I disassemble the framework and go from there. CTCallCopyName's function prototype is: CFTypeRef CTCallCopyName(CTCallRef call);